# Where should I place my image files for OctoberCMS

Tags: css, image, styles, octobercms

Im currently developing a website using OCtoberCMS and Im using a bootstrap theme provided by Hamberns, I want to customize my jumbotron by placing image overlay. My question is where do place my image files? OctoberCMS file structure is very confusing for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically will put the images in `themes/[theme-name]/assets/images`. Then you can reference that file in your template like this: `<img src="{{ 'assets/images/your-image.jpg'|theme }}" alt="My Image" />`

Comment: Thank you! Was wondering where to put images that I place it outside of theme folders. I also found out you can also upload pictures from the backend and you can just call it via twig, is it recommended though?

Comment: You bet. Sure, that is a fine way to do it as well.